# Why is this Regex not working to parse Javascript item?

Tags: python, regex, json, scrapy

I am using Python.org version 2.7 64 bit on Windows Vista 64 bit. I have the following code that is using a Regex to parse data stored in the Javascript item called `DataStore.prime('standings', { stageId: 7794 }`,:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
import csv
import re
import json

class MySpider(Spider):

    name = "goal2"
    allowed_domains = ["whoscored.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/Seasons/3853"] 

    def parse(self, response):

        match = re.search(re.escape("DataStore.prime('standings', { stageId: 7794 }, ") \
                     + '(\[.*\])' + re.escape(")],"), response.body)

        if match is not None:
            playerdata = match.group(1)

            for player in json.loads(playerdata):
                print str(playerdata)
```

Whilst this code is not producing an error, it is also not printing any output either. Can anyone tell me why this is not working?

Thanks

EDIT:

As per comments section below, here is a stripped down version of the above question, featuring only the Regex and what I am trying to parse with it:

Here is the Regex:

```
match = re.search(re.escape("DataStore.prime('standings', { stageId: 7794 }, ") \
                         + '(\[.*\])' + re.escape(")],"), response.body)
```

What I would like this to do is print out separately all the elements of what looks like a list within the Javascript item as individual items.

Here is an example of what I am trying to parse:

```
DataStore.prime('standings', { stageId: 7794 }, [[7794,167,'Manchester City',1,38,27,5,6,102,37,65,86,1,19,17,1,1,63,13,50,52,3,19,10,4,5,39,24,15,34,'<a class="d h" id="720744" title="Manchester City 2-2 Sunderland"/><a class="w h" id="720845" title="Manchester City 3-1 West Bromwich Albion"/><a class="w a" id="720867" title="Crystal Palace 0-2 Manchester City"/><a class="w a" id="720866" title="Everton 2-3 Manchester City"/><a class="w h" id="720778" title="Manchester City 4-0 Aston Villa"/><a class="w h" id="720887" title="Manchester City 2-0 West Ham"/>','<a class="w h" id="720799" title="Manchester City 5-0 Fulham"/><a class="w h" id="720823" title="Manchester City 4-1 Southampton"/><a class="d h" id="720744" title="Manchester City 2-2 Sunderland"/><a class="w h" id="720845" title="Manchester City 3-1 West Bromwich Albion"/><a class="w h" id="720778" title="Manchester City 4-0 Aston Villa"/><a class="w h" id="720887" title="Manchester City 2-0 West Ham"/>','<a class="w a" id="720786" title="Hull 0-2 Manchester City"/><a class="w a" id="720771" title="Manchester United 0-3 Manchester City"/><a class="d a" id="720807" title="Arsenal 1-1 Manchester City"/><a class="l a" id="720833" title="Liverpool 3-2 Manchester City"/><a class="w a" id="720867" title="Crystal Palace 0-2 Manchester City"/><a class="w a" id="720866" title="Everton 2-3 Manchester City"/>'], [#Multiple further similar lists containing more data#]])
```

Comment: Can you strip this down to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Give us a 3-line program with a string that you expect the regexp to match and the `re.search` that fails, everything else is irrelevant (and makes your code much harder to test and debug locally).

Comment: Also, while I don't think it's your problem, you should really use raw strings for regexp literals: `r'(\[.*\])'`. Otherwise, you're relying on the fact that `[` happens to not be a backslash escape in Python, and that Python (unlike most languages) leaves the backslash intact in unknown backslash escapes, and that everyone who reads your code will know that.

Comment: @abanert i have amended the question above in line with your suggestion. thanks

Comment: @MatteoItalia ive used this method previously on another json item in a different format and it worked ok.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to match here, but look at this part of your regexp:

```
'(\[.*\])' + re.escape(")],")
```

In other words, you're looking for a literal `])],`. And there is no such substring anywhere in the string.

I think you probably have another problem, but I'm not sure about this one: You're looking for `\[.*\]`. Your input has double brackets in it, and that pattern is going to match everything up to *and including* the first bracket as part of the `.*` and the second with the `]`, while I suspect you want the first bracket to match the `]` and the second to match something later in your pattern. If so, you need `.*?` here.

You might want to find a visual regexp explorer tool—there are dozens of them, online and downloadable, that will do things like color-matching the parts that match, updating the match in real time as you edit, etc. That may be easier than trying to explain to us what exactly you're trying to do.

Also, constructing a regexp string out of a mix of hand-escaped pieces and `re.escape` calls seems like it's almost bound to lead to you confusion with your escaping at some point. Not using raw strings doesn't help.

Finally, you should consider using the `re.VERBOSE` flag. It lets you write regular expressions that are a lot easier to read and debug.

Actually, not finally, one last thing: If you're trying to pull JavaScript literals out of JavaScript code, and they happen to be in JSON-compatible format, it can sometimes be helpful—at least in initial development—to write the simplest possible regexp that can pull out the JSON-compatible part, and `json.loads` that instead of trying to break it down with regexp syntax.

---

From your comment:

> basically there are a set of values contained within [] brackets. as a starting point i would like to obtain all of those and print them out.

OK, I'm not sure what all the other stuff in your regexp is supposed to do in that case, but this is easy:

```
for match in re.findall(r'\[.*?\]', response.body):
```

> the various values within the [] are separated by commas. ideally i would like to be able to print each of these elements individually.

While you could do that in the same regexp, it's a bit ugly, and there's a much simpler solution:

```
    for value in match.split(','):
        print(value)
```

Comment: basically there are a set of values contained within [] brackets. as a starting point i would like to obtain all of those and print them out. the various values within the [] are separated by commas. ideally i would like to be able to print each of these elements individually. thanks

Comment: how do i point 'for match in re.findall(r'\[.*?\]'):' to the datastore instance i am scanning? in my original regex i am using re.search to find it within the html source. would it be something like 'for match in re.search("DataStore.prime('standings', { stageId: 7794 }, "(re.findall(r'\[.*?\]')):'? thanks

Comment: @user3045351: Sorry, I forgot to include the string you're searching in the call. You pass it the same way you do in your original code. I'll edit my answer.